# Not able to create an s3 bucket using AWS Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am trying to write a simple script to connect to AWS s3 and create a bucket but I keep getting `Access Denied (Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied)`

This is my code

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'csv'

def test()
    creds = CSV.read('accessKeys.csv')
    s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
        region: 'us-west-2',
        credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(creds[1][0], creds[1][1]),
    )      
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3_client)

    s3.create_bucket({
        bucket: "dns-complaint-bucket",
    })
end

test()
```

I have also attached `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to the IAM user that I am using.

Comment: what about policy at bucket level ?

Comment: Use the awscli with the same credentials. Does 'aws s3 mb s3://mybucket' work?

Comment: Why are you reading credentials from a text file? Is this code running on an Amazon EC2 instance (if so, you should assign an IAM Role to the instance), or is it running on your own computer (if so, you should store credentials using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command)?